# Force download on Mongoose Server

Tags: c++, http, mongoose-web-server

I'm developing a RESTful API using Mongoose Web Server. I'm sending a file using

```
mg_send_file(conn, path, NULL);
```

but if the file is plain text, or a PDF, it just displays in the browser, instead of forcing the download, which is what I need.
How can I achieve that?

Thanks

--- Update:

I also tried to use

```
const char* extraHeaders = "Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename=somefilename.txt";
mg_send_file(conn, "somefilename.txt", extraHeaders);
return MG_MORE;
```

but the connection keeps running, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution was:

```
const char* extraHeaders = "Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename=\"somefilename.txt\"\r\n";
mg_send_file(conn, "somefilename.txt", extraHeaders);
return MG_MORE;
```

Note the filename between "", and the \r\n at the end of any extra header.